# Why leaders are leaving in the middle of Pu-Yi's speech?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-last-emperor

In the movie, "The Last Emperor EXTENDED", Why leaders are leaving from Pu-Yi's​ speech about Manchukuo?

> Pu-Yi: It is rooted in paternal trust, in... in the desire to preserve our ancient traditions, and in a mutual respect for our national identities.

[image]